# Jenkins - run pytest that suspected to fail and get the error data in failure case (but not failing the build)

Tags: jenkins, pytest

I have several pytest tests that I want to run but not as mandatory. It means that in case of failure the Jenkins build will pass successfully but I'll get all the error data.

I tried to do such thing using +e command:

```
sh("set +e; pytest
--junitxml=$WORKSPACE/test-reports/pytestSourceResults.xml -k TestCode; set -e;")
```

The build indeed didn't fail but I got unstable build result from jenkins.
How can I do something similar but get success in failure case?

Comment: `pytest || true`?

Comment: Thanks, I'm looking for a built-in ('real') solution, not for a workaround

Comment: If you know the kind of errors (or warnings) produced by these tests, you could use the [Log Parser plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/log-parser/) to filter them out (e.g. not consider them as errors/warnings for Jenkins). The plugin allows regular expressions to define what consists an error or warning.

Comment: don't you want to use xfail to mark those tests as "expected failures"?  (as described in doc.pytest.org/en/latest/skipping.html)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue using pytest with AWS codebuild.

Not sure if its an option for you but I changed to the unittest library and it works.